# Закрытие методов класса в наследниках

Tags: c++

Есть несколько классов `DriverProperty_p` — прототип свойств драйвера, `DriverProperty<T>` — свойство доступное для чтения-записи. `DriverPropertyReadOnly< T >` и `DriverPropertyWriteOnly< T >` — свойства доступные только для чтения или записи. В качестве буфера данных использую `QByteArray`. В прототипе реализованы все необходимые функции отправки и получения данных в/из устройства. Есть следующий код (привожу только header):

```
class DriverProperty_p
{
public:
    DriverProperty_p(AbstractDriver * parent, QString name, quint8 cmdGetter, quint8 cmdSetter = 0xFF);

    QByteArray getValue();
    void setValue(QByteArray value);

    QString getName() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);

    quint8 getCmdGetter() const;
    void setCmdGetter(const quint8 &cmdGetter);

    quint8 getCmdSetter() const;
    void setCmdSetter(const quint8 &cmdSetter);

private:
    AbstractDriver *mDriver;
    QString mName;
    QByteArray mValue;
    quint8 mCmdGetter;
    quint8 mCmdSetter;
};

template <typename T>
class DriverProperty: public DriverProperty_p
{
    using DriverProperty_p::setValue;
    using DriverProperty_p::getValue;
public:
    DriverProperty(AbstractDriver * parent, QString name, quint8 cmdGetter, quint8 cmdSetter = 0xFF)
        : DriverProperty_p(parent, name, cmdGetter, cmdSetter)
    {}
    static T convertFromByteArray(const QByteArray &ba);
    static QByteArray convertToByteArray(const T & data);

    T getValue()
    {
        return convertFromByteArray(DriverProperty_p::getValue();
    }
    void setValue(T value)
    {
        DriverProperty_p::setValue(convertToByteArray(value));
    }
};

template <typename T>
class DriverPropertyReadOnly: public DriverProperty<T>
{
    using DriverProperty<T>::setValue;
public:
    DriverPropertyReadOnly(AbstractDriver * parent, QString name, quint8 cmdGetter)
        : DriverProperty<T>(parent, name, cmdGetter)
    {}
};
template <typename T>
class DriverPropertyWriteOnly: public DriverProperty<T>
{
    using DriverProperty<T>::getValue;
public:
    DriverPropertyWriteOnly(AbstractDriver * parent, QString name, quint8 cmdGetter)
        : DriverProperty<T>(parent, name, cmdGetter)
    {}
};
```

При попытке компиляции кода выдает ошибку о том, что недоступен `DriverProperty_p::setValue`.

Вообще цель подобного кода заключалась в том, чтобы реализовать все функции в классе общего назначения (`DriverProperty< T >`) (и он работает как надо), а затем скрыть для использования соответствующие методы у потомков. Ну и основной мой вопрос: как правильно скрывать методы в потомках класса.

Comment: Ну для начала вам необходимо использовать private наследование или агрегирование. `using DriverProperty_p::setValue;` тут явно делает не то, что вы думаете, что оно делает.

Comment: @user7860670 А не могу использовать приватное наследование, поскольку в драйвере лежит основной массив всех свойств именно как QVector<DriverProperty_p*>. После приватного наследования DriverProperty_p становится недоступной базой для DriverProperty

Comment: В вопросе `QVector<DriverProperty_p*>` нигде не фигурирует, и вообще явно не является существенным для рассматриваемого вопроса.  *"После приватного наследования DriverProperty_p становится недоступной базой для DriverProperty"* - ну так вы же сами написали, что хотите скрыть его методы в потомках класса.

Comment: Вы себе дайте отчет в том, что делаете. Вы говорите, пусть  обьекты DriverProperty используют  setValuе своего базового класса, а потом определяете для них другой  setValuе который не  может быть использован. А если его не определить, то  и без вашего разрешения на общедоступность, обьекты производного будут использовать метод базового. Вы говорите: " Дети, вы можете прыгать  по своему _ вот так, но всегда прыгайте как я".  Так они и прыгали бы так, как вы . Зачем им говорить как могут это сделать и запрещать.?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно Вы имеете ввиду это?

```
#include <iostream>

#define PURE_VIRTUAL =0

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

class AbstractDriver
{
public:
    virtual void A() PURE_VIRTUAL;
    virtual void B() PURE_VIRTUAL;
};

class Driver_1 : public AbstractDriver
{
public:
    virtual void A() override { cout << "A" << endl; }
    virtual void B() override { cout << "B" << endl; }
};

class Driver_1_1 : protected Driver_1
{
public:
    void A() override { Driver_1::A(); };
};

int main()
{

    Driver_1 a;
    Driver_1_1 b;

    a.A(); a.B();

    b.A(); b.B();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Код не скомпилируется потому что `b.B()` недоступен

Comment: Ну вобщем то да, но мне кажется, что мой вариант решения с добавлением интерфейсов более правильный. К тому же тот код, который я привожу является лишь частью всего кода целиком. А так я сделал наоборот. Я не закрываю методы, а открываю, через добавление интерфейсов

Comment: `B()` тут по-прежнему доступен, так как наследование `Driver_1` публичное.

Comment: @Roman, Ваш вариант в этом отношение правильный, однако я считаю, что более естественно скрывать то, что не должно быть использовано, чем добавлять ещё один слой, который, по сути, перевызывает существующий функционал. Больше кода.

Comment: Ошибка будет из-за того, что `Driver_1_1::B не доступен`, а `Driver_1::B` и `AbstractDriver::B` по-прежнему доступны и позволяют косвенно вызвать `Driver_1_1::B`. Установка приватного спецификатора доступа для метода замещающего public метода public базового класса бесполезна.

Comment: @user7860670, vc++2017 выдаст ошибку компиляции:
```Ошибка C2248 Driver_1_1::B: невозможно обратиться к private член, объявленному в классе "Driver_1_1"```. Да, вызвать методы косвенно остаётся возможно, не вижу в этом противоречий: пользователи класса ```Driver_1_1``` не будут иметь доступа к ```B()```

Comment: Так а этого и не нужно. Приватный спецификатор доступа `Driver_1_1::B` по сути тут ничего не защищает так как для вызова этого метода не обязательно обращаться к `Driver_1_1::B`.

Comment: @user7860670, не очень понимаю, что имеется ввиду?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103650/discussion-between---and-user7860670).

Comment: `Driver_1_1::B` можно вызвать например так `static_cast< Driver_1 &>(b).B();`.

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо! Исправил ответ

Comment: @Артем Большое спасибо, допилил Ваше решение под себя. Вроде как все Ок